# jquery input val not working

Tags: jquery

I am trying to set an "input text" with the value passed by a variable and I can not.

The html and js are below:

JS:

```
function clique_mapa(latlng) {        
    var value1_lat = $('#antena01_lat').val();
    var value1_log = $('#antena01_log').val();

    var value2_lat = $('#antena02_lat').val();
    var value2_log = $('#antena02_log').val();

    if (typeof value1_lat == 'undefined') {
        $('input[name=antena01_lat]').val(value1_lat);
        $('input[name=antena01_log]').val(value1_log);                        
    }
};
```

Html:

```
<div class="coluna menu">
    Latitude<br />
    <input type="text" name="antena01_lat"/> <br />
    Longitude<br />
    <input type="text" name="antena01_log"/> <br /><br />    

    <input type="button" id="clique_mapa" name="clique_mapa" value="Abrir mapa" />
</div>
```

tks

Comment: where is document ready?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to assign an id to your input

```
<input type="text" name="antena01_lat" id="antena01_lat"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have

```
if (typeof value1_lat == 'undefined')
```

Shouldn't this be

```
if (typeof value1_lat != 'undefined')
```

Comment: the code passing through the point $('input[name=antena01_lat]').val(value1_lat);